# How to check in F# whether object implements interface

Tags: interface, f#, types, compilation, typechecking

Prototypical code in C#:

```
if(obj1 is ISomeInterface) {
   do_something
}
```

Code in F# that doesn't compile:

```
match obj1 with 
| :? ISomeInterface -> do_something
| _ -> ()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
match box obj1 with 
| :? ISomeInterface -> do_something
| _ -> ()
```

Answer (score 16):

To add some explanation for the answers by desco and Brian - adding `box` is needed when the static type of the `obj1` value may not necessariliy be a .NET reference type.

If the type of `obj1` is `obj` (type alias for `System.Object`) then you can use pattern matching without any boxing, because the compiler already knows you have a reference type:

```
let obj1 : obj = upcast (...)
match obj1 with 
| :? ISomeInterface -> (do something)
```

The case where you need `box` is when the type of `obj1` is generic type parameter. In this case, your function can be called with both value types and reference types. Adding `box` ensures that you're performing type test on reference type (and not on value type, which is not possible).

Comment: I don't think this is correct - if you define `type T() = class end` and then try to match a value of that type against any interface, the compiler won't let you, even though a subclass might implement that interface.

Comment: @kvb: Exactly the situation I had! The method of casting to obj helped! Like match t :> obj with ...

Answer (score 6):

While `match box obj1 with ...` does the job, there is a `box` IL instruction emitted by F# compiler. Box instruction is dangerous because it tends to be slow under some circumstances.

If you know that obj1 **is already a reference type** then a faster `:> obj` approach is recommended:

```
match obj1 :> obj with
    | :? ISomeInterface -> (do something)
```

`obj1 :> obj` is equivalent to C# `(object)obj1` type cast operation. Moreover, F# compiler optimizes out that excessive cast operation when the project is built in Release configuration, so you get the fastest code in this case.

Answer (score 3):

```
match box obj1 with ...
```

I think (typing from my phone :)